# How do I add a file upload button?

Tags: views, files

I have a view and have styled the view with a Twig template. The view show nodes whose content type is *Programs*. I would like to add a *Upload* button in the view so that admininistrator users can add reports. The view structure is the following one.

> [image: screenshot]

Is this possible through the Drupal UI?

I created the *File upload* field as a file type, but it is allowing administrators to add files only through the node page.
Is there a way to make the upload button appear on the view itself?

Comment: You could let your view display entity operations and then add a custom operation "upload file" which opens a custom form (maybe in a modal) to upload the file and attach it to a node in this form's submit handler. Or simply use the existing "edit node" entity operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a beta version of a module that can help you achieve this:

https://www.drupal.org/project/views_entity_form_field

> This module provides the ability to add form field widgets to a view to edit multiple entities at one time.
>
> Form field options will show up in a View's "Add field" list, prefixed with "Form field: " and then the name of the field being added.

Comment: Thanks ! this helped me :)